# Permissions; Cloud Run continuous deployment from Code Source Repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, google-source-repositories

I am having a hard time finding good documentation about this but I am looking to enable continuous integration between my web application running in Cloud Run, and my code replicated from Gitlab to Source Code Repository. The Cloud Run instance and Code Source are on different projects on shared VPCs. In Cloud Run, when I click on Continuous Integration and then click the dropdown to select the repository, nothing is there. I assume this is related to Cloud Run not having permission to GCP Source code but I've not been able to figure this out even after following GCP documentation.

Could you please provide me with some instructions on how I can get this to work? I understand that this functionality utilizes several services including Artifact Registry and Cloud Build, both of which are enabled in the Cloud Run project.

Thank you,

-Ronny

I tried following the instructions in the following document: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build